# How do you write commands in blender from a python script run outside blender?

Tags: python, terminal, subprocess, blender, bpy

I am trying to find a wat to add virices in a subprocess.Popen opened blender using the script that opened it to write the bpy codes into the blender proces. If this isn't possible, is there a wat to make the blender python receive (through a script run in blender) messages from the python script run in terminal (I am using fedora)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed - you have thought half the answer for yourself - 
The blender modules won't be available from outside blender, but
you can have a script inside blender to receive data from outside.

The easiest way would be to use XMLRPC - use a script that 
loads with Blender, and stars a Python XMLRPC server -
then you will be able to send commands into that script from 
outside.

It is easier than it sounds - check the Python documentation
for XMLRPC (it will even allow you to have python 2.7 scripts
outside blender communicating with the Python 3 that
runs inside blender) -

http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/xmlrpc.server.html#module-xmlrpc.server

Comment: Just make shure to note xmlrpc.client is xmlrpclib in python 2.7